# Typesetting generic types in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I would like to typeset generic types (eg `Foo<T>`) in math mode; for instance:

```
$\mathbf{Foo<T>} = R^3$
```

But the spacing around `<` and `>` is of course incorrect for this. Is there an easy way to have them be treated as normal characters in this context ?

Comment: Isn't this all considered as text, I mean both the word `Foo` and the `<T>` ?

Comment: `$\mathbf{Foo{\boldsymbol<}T{\boldsymbol>}}$` does it.

Comment: Maybe `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`?

Comment: @Bernard this seems to do it, but is there a way to use the "boldness" of the context instead ? Thanks!

Comment: Boldness in text has nothing to do with boldness in math. But ‘Foo’ in the real document is what? Text?

Comment: If the context is boldface, you can simply use `Foo$\boldsymbol\langle $T$ \boldsymbol\rangle$` (\langle-\rangle would be better than > >, as suggested by @egreg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell TeX that `<` and `>`, in a specific context, should issue `\langle` and `\rangle`, additionally applying `\bm` to them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\type}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \activate@angle@brackets
  \mathcode`<="8000 \mathcode`>="8000
  \mathbf{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\activate@angle@brackets}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`< \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\bm{\langle}}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`> \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\bm{\rangle}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\type{Foo<T>} = R^3 < x$ % second < is normal

For comparison: $\langle\mathbf{T}\rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Sorry for the delay, during vacations I didn't see your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should regard such identifiers as verbatim material and write

```
\( \verb|Foo<T>| = R^3 \)
```

[image: Sample output]